# JTable does not show column names - JScrollPane used

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I try to create a `JTable` with the column names "User" and with the test data "data", but the column names do not get printed.

```
String [] [] data = {{"hallo","hallo","","","",""},
        {"hallo","hallo","","","",""}};     
String [] User = {"ID","Benutzername", "Name", "Vorname", "Geburtsdatum", "Wirt"};

tableUsers = new JTable(data,User);
tableUsers.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(500,50));
tableUsers.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
//add(new JScrollPane(tableUsers));
JTableHeader header = tableUsers.getTableHeader();
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
panel.add(header, BorderLayout.NORTH);
panel.add(tableUsers, BorderLayout.CENTER);
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(tableUsers);
add(scrollPane);
tableUsers.setBounds(29, 245, 580, 136);
contentPane.add(tableUsers);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You add your table to the JPanel panel, then you add panel to the scroll pane. So, now your scroll pane contains your table. Now, you need to add the *scroll pane* to the content pane. You should not be adding your tableUsers to multiple items.

Edit: I am adding my entire code I used to run and test since I think you're having a separate issue.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.JTableHeader;

public class Test {
    /**
     * Do this for thread safety
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createGUI();
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * create the JFrame
     */
    private static void createGUI() {
        JFrame jf = new JFrame();

        addComponents(jf.getContentPane());

        jf.setVisible(true);
        jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        jf.pack();
    }

    /**
     * add the components
     * @param pane
     */
    private static void addComponents(Container pane) {
        String [] [] data = {{"hallo","hallo","","","",""}, {"hallo","hallo","","","",""}};     
        String [] User = {"ID","Benutzername", "Name", "Vorname", "Geburtsdatum", "Wirt"};

        JTable tableUsers = new JTable(data,User);
        tableUsers.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(500,50));
        tableUsers.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
        //add(new JScrollPane(tableUsers));
        JTableHeader header = tableUsers.getTableHeader();
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        panel.add(header, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        panel.add(tableUsers, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(panel);
        pane.add(scrollPane);
        tableUsers.setBounds(29, 245, 580, 136);
        //pane.add(tableUsers);
    }
}
```

Comment: But I need to add the JTabel "tableUsers" to my contentPane, because otherwise it will not get printed in my GUI. With the code u added, my JTable will not get printed and when I add my JTable to my contentPane, the column names will still not get printed.

Comment: @gandaaflf He is correct man, you just add the scroll pane to your content pane, like he has done in the example he provided you.

Comment: I actually ran this code and I did indeed see your table. If you're not seeing it, your driver code has an issue somewhere.

Comment: I have my class public "User_Verwalten() throws SQLException {" where I have this code and this code get used in my main class where I create a new frame from User_Verwalten. "public static void main(String[] args) {
  EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
   public void run() {
    try {
     User_Verwalten frame = new User_Verwalten();
     frame.setVisible(true);
     
    } catch (Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
    }
   }
  });
 }" What I am doing wrong?

Comment: It's impossible for me to read code within comments without copy/pasting. Please edit your question in the future to post code. I've modified my answer to show you the version I got working. This should be a basic format to follow when developing a Swing GUI.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Now it works for me. I forgot to add "scrollPane.setBounds".

Answer (score 1):

> JTable does not show column names - JScrollPane used

You are not using the JTable and JScrollPane correctly.

The basic code should be:

```
JTable table = new JTable(...);
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane( table );
frame.add(scrollPane);
```

That is there is no need to:

1. use the JPanel. The table header is added to the "column header" of the scroll pane automatically.
2. set the bounds of the scroll pane. That is the job of the layout manager.

Comment: Thank you very much, after I added "scrollPane.setBounds" it is working!

Comment: @gandaaflf, there is no need for "scrollPane.setBounds(...)". If this is the solution you have a bigger problem somewhere else in your code. Post a proper [mre] demonstrating the problem.